# NodeJS & Big Json Data

Tags: json, node.js

What is the best way to parse Json data?

The data I want to parse is this http://auction-api-us.worldofwarcraft.com/auction-data/1df2364d502d1d8a765b114f0da56207/auctions.json

However, I need to check what "item" is, at the moment I loop all "auctions", grab "item" and then do what I need to from there. However its so slow, and it takes way to long. Is there a better way to do this?

Would love some advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this `big-json-streamer` library for node.

Read more about it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-json-streamer)